# refresh_token grant type supplies another refresh token?

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2

While developing my Spring Rest API I am noticing something I don't quite understand. I am using the `refresh_token` grant type. It works fine when I access `/myapi/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token` but I am confused as to why it returns a shiny new refresh token along with a new access token.

Wouldn't this render the expiration time of the refresh token useless? If they can use a refresh token to get another refresh token, wouldn't they have unlimited refresh tokens?

edit: relevant parts of OAuth config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("abcd1234");
    return accessTokenConverter;
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    return defaultTokenServices;
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("myclient")
            .secret("mysecret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .scopes("read")
            .autoApprove("read")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(300)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(12000);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.accessTokenConverter()));
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant OAuth2 security config? That might be helpful here.

Comment: @Eugen I have posted my oauth config, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the OAuth2 [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5) (point H), it is okay to optionally return a new refresh token when refreshing the access token, so the behavior is inline with the spec.

Spring Boot provides the `reuseRefreshToken` flag to control this behavior. It is set to true by default, which means refresh tokens *should* be reused and it should *not* generate new refresh tokens when you request a new access token.

However, in case of JWT tokens, there is a open [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1109) due to which, the flag value seems to be ignored and a new refresh token generated every time in `JwtAccessTokenConverter#enhance()` method.

Side Note: The `reuseRefreshToken` flag can be set on an instance of `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` or by exposing a bean of type `DefaultTokenServices` and setting the flag in it.